# C# WPF Window Width, MaxWidth, MinWidth ignored

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window, width

I have a WPF Window defined in XAML like this:

```
<Window x:Class="com.some.company.window"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="My Cool Window" 
x:Name="CoolWindow"
Height="435"
Width="70"
MinWidth="70"
MaxWidth="70"
Left="{PropertyState Default=0}"
Top="{PropertyState Default=0}"
Initialized="InitializeWindow"
ResizeMode="NoResize"  
Style="{DynamicResource DefaultWindow}">
.....
.....
</Window>
```

The problem is that when the Window is created and displayed on the screen - it is ALWAYS larger than the 70 pixels I specified in the width definition. The width is probably 80-90 pixels. My width attributes are ignored. None of the contents inside the Window are larger than 70 pixels either.

Even when I try to resize the window with the grips, it will not let me resize it below a specific width. Is there some reason WPF is not letting me set the width of the window smaller? Is there a hidden minimum width value for every window? and how would I get around this?

EDIT:
When I add WindowsStyle="None" into the Window attribute, the width is correctly set to 70 pixels. However, this is not the style I want for the Window.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe some of the window's contents are larger than your current window size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set `MinWidth` to 70 and therefore size of your `Window` cant be less than that.  BTW because of control box it's width seems to have a minimum limit of 132.

If we set `WindowStyle="none"`  to remove the title and control box, we can make the `Window` even smaller.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationUnleashed.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationUnleashed"
        Title="" WindowStyle="None" Width="70">
    <Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT**

To make the Window width to 70, while the close button, Title text still visible and no-resize use this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationUnleashed.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationUnleashed"
        Title="My Window" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" Width="70" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Since 70 is a very small width, you cant have minimize and maximize button along with close button.

Comment: I want the width to be exactly 70, but when the Window displays, it's always around 80-90 pixels instead of the 70 pixels i want

Comment: remove the control box as i suggested and then you can set width to 70 by setting Width=70 on window.

Comment: I know if I use WindowStyle="none", it will respect the width=70. However, I cannot use WindowStyle="none" because my application requires the Windows chrome and close buttons in the title bar. What control box are you referring to?

Comment: try setting  WindowStyle="ToolWindow" Width="70" ResizeMode="NoResize". This does not remove the close button.

Answer (score 2):

70 that you have specified is not in pixels. WPF works on points and it actually sizes window to pixels based on Screen DPI (Dots per Inch).

Comment: I guess by pixels he is referring to DIU(Device Independent Units) :)

Comment: If your desktop scaling (Windows setting, not an app setting) is set to 125%, then a WPF window size (Width, MinWidth, MaxWidth, ActualWidth) of 70 will be 70x1.25=87.5 physical pixels.  There are ways to de-scale WPF apps back to hardware pixels, but it's not recommended because it causes issues in very-high DPI contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I wanted by adding WindowStyle="ToolWindow" and ResizeMode="NoResize". This allowed me to keep the titlebar and the close button, while allowing the window's width to be set at 70pt.